# Pandas - Merging on A->B or B->A

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have a dataframe `df1` that just has columns `From` and `To`. I have a separate dataframe `df2` that contains columns `Source` and `Destination` among others. I want to merge `df1` and `df2` either by matching `From` and `To` on `Source` and `Destination` OR by matching `To` and `From` on `Source` and `Destination`. In other words I want to check for both A->B and B->A. Is there an easy way to do this? I want the resulting dataframe to have all of the information from `df1`.

```
In [2]: df1
Out[2]: 
   To From
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  4  6

In [2]: df2
Out[2]: 
   Source  Destination
0   1          2
1   10         13       
2   6          4
```

Here, I would want it to merge on the 1 and 2 (row 0) but also it should merge the 4/6 row on 6/4.

Comment: Please see [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide a [mcve] including desired output and code for what you've tried so far, and what was wrong with your attempts

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: would you be able to show the expected result? the last line:`I want the resulting dataframe to have all of the information from df1` confuses me